# Does Azure AD B2C expose a metadata endpoint as WS-Federation relying party?

Tags: azure, metadata, adfs, azure-ad-b2c, ws-federation

I have ADFS as WS-Federation identity provider for Azure B2C tenant.
I was using this instruction from Micorosft https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/blob/master/Documentation/Features%20part%204.md#using-ad-fs-as-a-claims-provider

What is the Azure B2C metadata URL for WS-federation ?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the publicly available documentation Azure AD B2C doesn't. You may be able to check with MS support or identity forums on what stage of development/preview roadmap it's at.

Here is the public documentation I am referring to - [Release notes for Azure Active Directory B2C custom policy public preview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-developer-notes-custom#features-by-stage-and-known-issues)

[image]

On a side note, SAML2 based metadata endpoint is available and I've seen samples of people using it, but I guess you would've come across it anyway while searching for the WS-Fed one :)

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/te/<yourtenant>.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1a_<yourpolicy>/Samlp/metadata?idptp=<TechnicalProfile-id>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not supported.

Go SAML to ADFS.

If you have to use WS-Fed, put identityserver, Auth0, Okta etc. in the middle and go SAML in / WS-Fed out.